# Factory method pattern extension

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I have a `Project` class that can be subclassed as `MasterProject` or `SubProject`. I am using the factory method pattern to create instances of these classes. For this question, only `MasterProject` is important. Below is the `ProjectFactory.vb` file:

```
Public MustInherit Class ProjectFactory
    Protected MustOverride Function CreateProject(restResponse As Object) As Project
    Public MustOverride Function GetProject(restResponse As Object) As Project
End Class

Public Class MasterProjectFactory
    Inherits ProjectFactory

    Protected Overrides Function CreateProject(projectID As Object) As Project
        Return New MasterProject(projectID("Project_mpBaseProjectID_c"))
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetProject(projectID As Object) As Project
        Dim masterProject = CreateProject(projectID)

        Return masterProject
    End Function

End Class

Public Class SubProjectFactory
    Inherits ProjectFactory

    Protected Overrides Function CreateProject(restResponse As Object) As Project
        ' Do stuff
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetProject(restResponse As Object) As Project
        ' Do stuff
    End Function
End Class
```

Currently, a `MasterProject` is created using the `restResponse` object. If I wanted to have an option to create the `MasterProject` by passing either the whole `restResponse` object, or a single string, how would I go about it? I have a few ways in mind which I will share below, but I'm wondering which one is the most correct (following the factory method pattern)?

**#1**

From what I saw and read about the factory method design pattern, it is useful to have the `GetProject` method as in the example above so we can do any necessary manipulations before returning the project. Following that, I can check the type of the passed variable and call the corresponding `CreateProject` method that has a string overload and an object overload:

```
Public Class MasterProjectFactory
    Inherits ProjectFactory

    Protected Overrides Function CreateProject(projectID As Object) As Project
        Return New MasterProject(projectID("Project_mpBaseProjectID_c"))
    End Function

    Protected Overloads Function CreateProject(projectID As String) As Project
        Return New MasterProject(projectID)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetProject(projectID As Object) As Project
        Dim masterProject As MasterProject

        If projectID.GetType() Is GetType(String) Then
            masterProject = CreateProject(projectID)
        Else
            masterProject = CreateProject(projectID)
        End If

        Return masterProject
    End Function
End Class
```

But the problem I see here is that I cannot differentiate which `CreateProject` method I'm calling. Maybe there's a way in VB.NET/C# to specify this, but I'm wondering if this is even a good practice?

**#2**

The second option that makes more sense to me would be to simply check the type of the passed argument `projectID` (`restResponse` in the first code block) and construct the object with it. I don't know if this is following the factory method pattern.

```
Public Class MasterProjectFactory
    Inherits ProjectFactory

    Protected Overrides Function CreateProject(projectID As Object) As Project
        If projectID.GetType() Is GetType(String) Then
            Return New MasterProject(projectID)
        Else
            Return New MasterProject(projectID("Project_mpBaseProjectID_c"))
        End If
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetProject(projectID As Object) As Project
        Dim masterProject = CreateProject(projectID)

        Return masterProject
    End Function
End Class
```

I'd just like to point out that I know that there is no need to follow the pattern to the letter. Patterns are used situationally the best way they fit. I'm just looking for a general best practice rule to follow here.

Comment: Can you cite a well-known source for the reputed *Factory* pattern? GoF defines *Abstract Factory* and *Factory Method* patterns, but no pattern just named *Factory*. There are other sources of patterns than GoF, but I wonder why people keep referring to an ostensible *Factory* pattern. Where is it defined?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have so many `Object`s around?  Also as an aside, it's a little more canonically VB to use `TypeOf ... Is` than `... .GetType() Is`, though they should both have the same effect.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much point to #1 unless your two functions are substantially simplified.  If they're one-liners like this, then you might as well do it all inline---it can be converted back later if it gets more complicated.

Comment: I was using `Object` in signatures since I wanted to just pass the REST call result to the factory and let the factory do all the initialization, instead of passing the `"Project_mpBaseProjectID_c"` property. I could've just past the needed property, but I feel like this way it's more extendible.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, TutorialsPoint has been confusing and misleading developers for years with its [Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) and [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm) articles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Visual Basic programmer, but I know how .NET works. Would it be a solution to cast `projectID` to `String` if it is, indeed, a `String`?

```
Public Overrides Function GetProject(projectID As Object) As Project
    Dim masterProject As MasterProject

    If projectID.GetType() Is GetType(String) Then
        masterProject = CreateProject(CType(projectID, String))
    Else
        masterProject = CreateProject(projectID)
    End If

    Return masterProject
End Function
```

Comment: This answers how I would differentiate the two overloaded methods in the first case. But I'm still unsure what would be a better way to go about this problem. Am I getting too focused on the details of the implementation or is one way better than the other?

Comment: @lukaabra Sorry, I may have misunderstood the question. I think that *Craig* has a good point in the comments. Why do you need the overloads when all is as simple as this?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. That's why I'm asking. Maybe I'm just trying to over-engineer it.

Comment: @lukaabra A design pattern is a general solution to a commonly occurring problem in a context. If you don't have the problem, then you don't need the solution.

Comment: I fell for one of the most commonly mentioned pitfalls when learning design patterns - trying to implement them everywhere and overthinking them.